# Recommendations for a Precision Seeder for Planting Perennial Seeds in a 100-cell Tray

Tags: seeds, germination, perennials

I am looking for recommendations on a precision seeder that is suitable for planting perennial seeds in a 100-cell tray. The seeds I am working with are very small, and I need a seeder that can handle this type of delicate seeding operation.

Specifically, I am interested in a seeder that can provide accurate and uniform seed placement in each cell of the tray. The tray has 100 cells, and I want to ensure that the seeds are planted at the right depth and spacing for optimal germination.

I have heard about pneumatic seeders being suitable for such tasks. Can anyone recommend specific models or brands that have proven to be effective for planting small seeds in tray setups?

Additionally, if there are any considerations or modifications that I should be aware of when using such seeders for perennial seeds, I would greatly appreciate any insights.

Thank you in advance for your recommendations and expertise!

- Scutellaria incana
- Eupatorium maculatum ‘Riesenschirm’
- 'Transparent' - Molinia litoralis
- Actaea (Cimicifuga) racemosa
- Persicaria amplexicaulis 'Orange Field'
- Lobelia Vedrariensis
- Iris sibirica 'Perry's Blue'
- Dryopteris erythrosora
- Anemone × hybrida 'Honorine Jobert'
- Stachys officinalis 'Hummelo' (Bettony)
- Aster macrophyllus 'Twilight'
- Astrantia major 'Claret'
- Thalictrum dipterocarpum
- Deschampsia goldschleier
- Molinia caerulea 'Moorhexe'
- Monarda 'Jacob Cline'
- Fehér Tűzgyöngyvirág (Heuchera villosa)
- Digitalis ferruginea 'Gigantea'
- Hylomecon japonica
- Geranium 'Patricia'
- Paeonia hybrid 'Flame'
- Selinum
- Angelica

Comment: Sorry, but shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I do question whether you are overcomplicating things - in order for a pneumatic seeder system to make sense you would, I expect, need to be doing HUGE volumes.   Why not just use tweezers and a bit of care?   I expect the variance in seeds will be a bigger factor then the slight differences in depth.

Comment: Again, I think its overkill, but if you are dead set on getting perfect germination depths, maybe you could 3d print some kind of rig.  I'd also be curious how you would find the perfect depth for each plant seed though?

Comment: Typically, seeds are planted at the same depth as their diameter, so very small seeds are simply put on top of the soil. If the seed requires darkness to germinate, just cover the cell with an opaque material. You'll probably want at least two seeds per cell anyway, in case germination is poor.

Comment: I just read today in "Prairie Moon Nursery" catalog that outdoor sewing is your best bet. I thought of you, though you may not like the low-tech sensibility: 
“To naturally stratify seed, surface sow **outdoors** in late fall through winter on a bare, weed-fee site and allow seed to overwinter. If you are new to perennial seed starting, this would be the preferred method." Perennials will germinate better after feeling and passing a winter.